# whats wrong with this code it just give Enter an Alphabet= j ERROR! (Enter one Alphabet only not two Alphabet or a number)

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
char a;
printf("Enter an Alphabet=\n");
scanf("%c",&a);
if(a>=0)
{
    printf("ERROR!\n(Enter one Alphabet only not two Alphabet or a number)");
}
else
{
    switch (a)
{
    case 'a' :
    printf("It is vowel");
    break;
    case 'e' :
    printf("It is vowel");
    break;
    case 'i' :
    printf("It is vowel");
    break;
    case 'o' :
    printf("It is vowel");
    break;
    case 'u' :
    printf("It is vowel");
    break;
    default :
        printf("it is a constant");
}
}
return 0;
}
```

this code just give this result

```
Enter an Alphabet=
r
ERROR!
(Enter one Alphabet only not two Alphabet or a number)
--------------------------------
Process exited after 2.259 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: There's nothing C++-specific in your code, it could all be plain C. What resource are you using to learn C++?

Comment: What's the value of `a`?

Comment: As for your problem, any input given ***will*** be larger or equal to `0`. There are no characters that will be negative. What is the check `a >= 0` supposed to check for?

Comment: Why are you checking if `a` is greater than zero? All ascii characters are greater than zero so this will only be false if you enter a non ascii character (assuming `char` is signed)

Comment: And I guess you're looking for the [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) function to check if a character is alphabetic. I also recommend you learn about e.g. [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower), and [the other standard character functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte).

Comment: And *always* check [what `scanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: Lastly, `printf("it is a constant")` should be `printf("it is a consonant")`. There's a typo in your output.

Comment: i just want the user not to enter a number

Comment: i am new to this site how to reply to a specific person.

Comment: @GhostBoy Off-topic: use @ to reply to someone. See also the [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a character is an alphabetical character, you should use the [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) function.

Putting together my other pointer (checking what [`scanf` returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value) as well as using [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower), the code could be written something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a;

    printf("Enter an alphabetical character: ");
    if (scanf(" %c", &a) != 1)
    {
        printf("Error reading input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!isalpha(a))
    {
        printf("Character is not an alphabetical character\n");
        return 1;
    }

    switch (tolower(a))
    {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
        printf("It's a vowel\n");
        break;

    default:
        printf("It's a consonant\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

<sub>[Note that the above code is still written in plain C, not C++]</sub>